# Com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, dagger-hilt

This is a simple app to get data from firebase

***Error:*** *[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.*
`public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector`

**Android Menifest**

```
<application 
  android:name=".MyApplication"
 ....
</application>
```

**MyApplication.class**

```
@HiltAndroidApp
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

**FirebaseModule.class**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class FirebaseModule {

    @Provides
    public FirebaseFirestore providesFirebaseFirestore() {
        return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    @Provides
    public FirebaseDatabase providesFirebaseDb() {
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(MOVIES)
    public CollectionReference providesMovies(FirebaseFirestore db) {
        return db.collection(MOVIES);
    }

}
```

**Repos.class**

```
@Singleton
 public class Repos {
  @Named(MOVIES)
    public CollectionReference movies;

  @Inject
    public Repos(CollectionReference movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing a web search for the error message "cannot be provided without an @ Inject constructor or an @ Provides-annotated method"?  It seems common.

Comment: @Doug Thank you for your suggestion. I figured out that it was due to placement of ```@Named```.